# Put, Delete... Method not allowed in Orchard

Tags: asp.net-web-api, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I've created WebApi controller based on following tutorial: [sebastienros website](http://sebastienros.com/web-api-makes-it-in-orchard)
My modules name is **Company.Accounts**.

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string LogIn([FromBody] UserModel user)
    {
        // this is working
        return this.accountService.LogIn(user.UserName, user.Password);
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public string SomePuthMethod([FromBody] UserModel user)
    {
        // method not allowed
        // some code...
    }
}
```

Implementation of **IHttpRouteProvider** looks like:

```
private IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetAccountRoute()
{
   yield return new HttpRouteDescriptor
   {
       Name = "Account",
       Priority = 10,
       RouteTemplate = "Api/Account",
       Defaults = new
       {
            area = "Company.Accounts",
            controller = "Account"
        }
    };
}
```

Unfortunately, everything except **GET** and **POST** **is not working**. I'm getting simple

> Method not allowed.

What's wrong? My Orchard version is 1.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

You put them in the MethodNames  `public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]...){}`